# Short question on functions of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

For a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ of locally bounded variation, when is $$\liminf_{e \to 0} V(f)[x, x+e]/e $$finite everywhere? Here $V(f)[a, b]$ denotes the total variation of the function on the interval $[a, b]$.

Comment: An obvious sufficient condition for this property is that $f$ be absolutely continuous with a locally bounded density. As for a necessary and sufficient condition, it is unclear in what terms you want such a characterization to be. I think it's possible that there are no (more or less) simple characterizations of this property, except for the trivial tautology: the property holds iff it holds. This property reminds me a bit the strong law of large numbers for not necessarily independent identically distributed random variables, for which I think no general nontrivial characterization exists.

Comment: Sorry, what did you mean by density?

Comment: By one of equivalent definitions of absolute continuity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), if $f$ is absolutely continuous, then the corresponding (signed) Lebesgue--Stieltjes measure $\mu_f$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. What I mean then by the density is the Radon--Nikodym density $d\mu_f/d\lambda$. Can you answer the question about desired/expected terms of the characterization of the property?

Comment: Hmm it’s hard to explain the full motivation, but I want something sort of like a weaker derivative for locally bounded variation functions.

Comment: Because requiring a derivstive to exist at every point would be a little too extreme for the class of BV functions, I want some kind of “rough” measure of the pointwise change in the function, if that makes sense?

Comment: In general, if $f$ is only known to be absolutely continuous with a locally bounded density, this guarantees the existence of a derivative $f'$ only almost everywhere, not necessarily everywhere. But I guess you want a necessary and sufficient condition.